# Git: Automatically add files to index before a push?

Tags: git, hook, push, addition

In our team we're working with an online git repository for a website. We wrote a post-receive hook, so everytime we push, git automatically makes a checkout into the remote workspace.

But the site owner has the possibility to change some backend things which results in altered or new files, which would be overwritten by our checkout hook.

So the question is, what can be done to prevent the remote files to be overwritten when there are changes?

Can git automatically add and commit new or changed files? Maybe with a cronjob?

Or what kind of workflow is appropriate? We don't want to lose the possibilty to just push in order to publish our changes.

Comment: What would you want git to automatically do in case of merge conflicts?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Is it better to avoid a push in the first place?
I mean, can git automatically check (before a push) that there are untracked or modified files and reject a push?

Comment: `git status --porcelain` should be workable if you've done a real checkout.  The real answer is to either stop tracking files the site owner touches or get the site owner to do `git commit -amlocal-change` after changing things.